# Xcode Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 issue

Tags: c, xcode, gcc, clang

I am trying to run a code from a C book on my mac using Xcode but I am having an issue when compile

I have a header file with a structure for Files and a buffer for it but I have an error on a method implementation when i try to use the buffer variable.

My header looks this way

```
#ifndef custio_h
#define custio_h
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define     EOF (-1)
#define     BUFSIZ 1024
#define     OPEN_MAX 20 /* max #files open at once */

typedef struct _iobuf {
    int cnt;        /* characters left */
    char *ptr;      /* next character position */
    char *base;     /* location of buffer */
    int flag;       /* mode of file access */
    int fd;         /* file descriptor */
} FILE;

extern FILE _iob[OPEN_MAX];

#define stdin   (&_iob[0])
#define stdout  (&_iob[1])
#define stderr  (&_iob[2])

enum _flags {
    _READ   = 01,   /* file open for reading */
    _WRITE  = 02,   /* file open for writing */
    _UNBUF  = 04,   /* file is unbuffered */
    _EOF    = 010,  /* EOF has ocurred on this file */
    _ERR    = 020   /* error ocurred on this file */
};

int _fillbuf(FILE *);
int _flushbuf(int, FILE *);
FILE *cfopen(char *, char *);

#define feof(p)     (((p)->flag & _EOF) != 0)
#define ferror(p)   (((p)->flag & _ERR) != 0)
#define fileno(p)   ((p)->fd)

#define getc(p)     (--(p)->cnt >= 0 ? (unsigned char) *(p)->ptr++ : _fillbuf(p))
#define putc(x,p)   (--(p)->cnt >= 0 ? *(p)->ptr++ = (x) : _flushbuf((x),p))

#define getchar()   getc(stdin)
#define puchar(x)   putc((x), stdout)



#endif /* custio_h */
```

And my implementation is this

```
#include "custio.h"
#define PERMS 0666

/* fopen: open file, return file pointer */
FILE *cfopen(char *name, char *mode)
{
    int fd;
    FILE *fp;

    if (*mode != 'r' && *mode != 'w' && *mode != 'a')
        return NULL;

    for (fp = _iob; fp < (_iob + OPEN_MAX); fp++)
        if ((fp->flag & (_READ | _WRITE)) == 0)
            break; /* found free slot */

    if (fp >= _iob + OPEN_MAX) /* no free slots */
        return NULL;

    if (*mode == 'w')
        fd = creat(name, PERMS);
    else if (*mode == 'a') {
        if ((fd = open(name, O_WRONLY, 0)) == -1)
            fd = creat(name, PERMS);
        long c = 10000000;
        lseek(fd, c, 2);
    } else
        fd = open(name, O_RDONLY, 0);

    if (fd == 1) /* could not access name */
        return NULL;

    fp->fd = fd;
    fp->cnt = 0;
    fp->base = NULL;
    fp->flag = (*mode == 'r') ? _READ : _WRITE;

    return fp;
}
```

The lines where i use the _iob are the problem.

the error says: 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__iob", referenced from:
      _cfopen in custio.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You need to put `FILE _iob[OPEN_MAX];` as a global variable into the `.c` file, the extern declaration in the header can be seen as sort of a forward declaration of a global variable.  You will have more problem though, because the functions `_fillbuf` and `_flushbuf` are also only forward-declared.

Comment: Ye man , I was missing the implementation on the array, i think is a newbie error. Thanks a lot for your help